# Create Job using Rundeckrun?

Tags: python, python-module, rundeck

Want to create a job using rundeckrun python module in Rundeck, I searched in their documentation, but couldn't find it.

Is there any other option to create a job using rundeckrun in Rundeck

Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was recently posted in the rundeckrun repo: [#17](https://github.com/marklap/rundeckrun/issues/17) (probably by you: @Naren). As I mentioned in the comments of that Github Issue, the Rundeck API doesn't provide a high level method of creating jobs so rundeckrun doesn't either... yet. :) However, the Rundeck API does provide a method of importing job definitions and rundeckrun provides a light wrapper around that endpoint. You can manipulate/create a job definition and import it. In fact, that's exactly what's done in the [`tests/__init__.py`](https://github.com/marklap/rundeckrun/blob/master/tests/__init__.py#L44) setup logic:

```
test_job_id = uuid.uuid4()
test_job_name = 'TestJobTest'
test_job_proj = 'TestProjectTest'
test_job_def_tmpl = """<joblist>
  <job>
    <id>{0}</id>
    <loglevel>INFO</loglevel>
    <sequence keepgoing='false' strategy='node-first'>
      <command>
        <node-step-plugin type='localexec'>
          <configuration>
            <entry key='command' value='echo "Hello World! (from:${{option.from}})"' />
          </configuration>
        </node-step-plugin>
      </command>
      <command>
        <node-step-plugin type='localexec'>
          <configuration>
            <entry key='command' value='sleep ${{option.sleep}}' />
          </configuration>
        </node-step-plugin>
      </command>
    </sequence>
    <description></description>
    <name>{1}</name>
    <context>
      <project>{2}</project>
      <options>
        <option name='from' value='Tester' />
        <option name='sleep' value='0' />
      </options>
    </context>
    <uuid>{0}</uuid>
  </job>
</joblist>"""
test_job_def = test_job_def_tmpl.format(test_job_id, test_job_name, test_job_proj)
```

And then [the creation of the job](https://github.com/marklap/rundeckrun/blob/master/tests/__init__.py#L107)...

```
def setup():
    rundeck_api.jobs_import(test_job_def, uuidOption='preserve')
```